# Wordpress: How to check if current post is saved/updated

Tags: wordpress

How can I check in backend if the current post is saved/updated or not.
I need to show an metabox after the post is saved/updated.
Literally after the "Update" Button is clicked.

something like this small sketch:

```
function add_aftersave_metabox() {
   ///how to do this:
   if ( $post == ?? is saved?? )
          remove_meta_box('you-have-to-save', 'post', 'normal');
          add_meta_box( 'post-is-saved', 'post', 'normal');   }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'add_aftersave_metabox');
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I understand, you don't just want to look at the blog section of your page to see if the post is posted, but you want to check it otherwise?

I am just curious as to why you may want to do so with Wordpress.

Comment: I want to check when i edit a post in the backend if this post is saved or if there are unsaved information. I want to show a metabox after the post is saved/updated. This metabox should only visible if the post is saved/updated. 
Like this:
if (notsaved) { please save the post first }
else {the post is saved}